# Where to store passwords in Windows via Java

Tags: java, security, passwords, registry, storage

I am creating a **Java** based **Desktop application**.
In it I need to store a password so that whenever someone tries to access the application, it asks for a password. I have encrypted the password using BCrypt, so it is (hopefully) secure.

However, I need to store the password somewhere safe. Initially, I considered storing it in the Windows registry (since my application is Windows specific). However, anyone can edit or delete the registry key, which is very insecure.

Therefore, I need to store the password in a place that the user cannot access or modify (and definitely not delete).

What is the safest way I could store the (already encrypted) password?
It would be helpful if you are Java specific.

**EDIT**

Some people have pointed out that I should use a database to store the password securely.
I tried it out and have successfully stored the password in the database and further retrieved it.
However, even the database needs to be stored somewhere, and hence if the database is deleted, the password is removed. This is therefore insecure.
What should I do in this scenario?

Comment: Why not use a database?

Comment: literally was writting that @Karthikeyan - after all, they're **designed to store data securely**

Comment: @MrCoder -  

I have tried using a database, however, even the database needs to be stored somewhere and if the database is deleted, the password is gone too! What should I do now?

Comment: @Karthikeyan - I have tried using a database, however, even the database needs to be stored somewhere and if the database is deleted, the password is gone too! What should I do now?

Comment: @PratanuMandal, and what about storing the database in the cloud? Have you considered that option? Also, if you make the database readonly, would that not make it more secure?

Comment: @MrCoder, I only intend to store the password so that the user can have an extra level of security when he uses the application so as to prevent unauthorized access. **The application specifically should not use the internet.** Storing in an offline database is no improvement in comparison to storing in the registry. Rather, it is slower. In either case, if someone deletes the registry key or the database, the password is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a database.

I am giving you a link which shows you how to use a MySQL database with Java.

http://www.lionblogger.com/java-application-mysql-database/

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I have tried using a database, however, even the database needs to be stored somewhere and if the database is deleted, the password is gone too! What should I do now?

Comment: Nope. The original question suggests that the data should be on user's computer. Also any program can access that database getting users password.

Answer (score 0):

where windows stores its passwords (which can ***still*** be 'cracked/hacked'):

Windows stores its passwords in what is called the Security Accounts Manager database, or SAM database.

This is a file that exists in the registry and access to it is tightly controlled whilst windows is running; however, local administrators who can run processes as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM can access it - see where does NT store the SAM database?.

Could you not use something like this (even if it IS a database, which you seem so put off by)?

---

## Option

---

Other than that, why wouldn't you just run this on a **password protected** database, in which requires authentication before you can edit/delete?  - It's probably the most sensible option

---

However, if you're still looking to 'store' your password, I'd like to quote this:

> Do not invent your own "clever" password storage scheme. I know,
> you're smart, and you grok this crypto stuff. But through this door
> lies madness-- and abominations like LMHash that have ongoing,
> worldwide security ramifications we're still dealing with today. Take
> advantage of whatever password storage tools your framework provides,
> as they're likely to be a heck of a lot better tested and more
> battle-proven than any crazy scheme you and your team can come up with
> on your own. Security vulnerabilities, unlike functionality bugs in
> your application, run deep and silent. They can lay dormant for years.

~[Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/) ,Co-founder of Stack Exchange and Discourse

Comment: I appreciate your perspective. I have indeed not tried to invent my own password hashing scheme. My application basically encrypts files with a password using AES system. The per-file password is hashed with BCrypt and stored inside the file.  
  
The second level of security is a password for the application itself. This I need to store in a secure manner.

Comment: and as everyone has suggested, store it in a database!

Comment: [here for SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/16/sql-server-making-database-to-read-only-changing-database-to-readwrite/)

Comment: But the problem is I don't know how to create a database that can't be deleted.
Till now, I have come up with the following code :

Comment: String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";    
    String dbName = "Database";
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";create=true";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
    String createString = createString = "CREATE TABLE PasswordTable (PASSWORD VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)";
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(createString);
    PreparedStatement psInsert = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PasswordTable VALUES (?)");
    psInsert.setString(1, password);
    psInsert.executeUpdate();

Comment: @PratanuMandal, what I don't think you realise is ***nothing on a PC is undeleteable*** - nor 100% secure.

Comment: Then what should I do? There must be a way to atleast make deleting stuff difficult. Or else, I am totally doomed, alas!

Comment: either hard coding the 'hashed' password in your application, or creating a read only database.

Comment: The password must be changeable. The user should be able to change the password.

Comment: I really thank you for your patience.
Well, but windows registry is just as effective then.
Could you please suggest how could I make the database files undeletable? (or even better undetectable)

Comment: [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-can-i-make-a-file-truly-undeletable/be2b10b3-9251-4f78-aeff-519cc490f12c)